# I am trying to reduce passive voice and verbose language in a graduate level thesis

Tags: passive-voice

My specific question is finding replacements for the phrase "in order for" and "in order to".  Example:

> Additionally, as global internet penetration increased there was an acute understanding that for access to the internet to remain free the internet would need to be supported.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you've already replaced *in order for* with *for* in your example sentence?

Comment: Rare is the sentence where "in order to/for" cannot be omitted. The problem with that sentence is you're requiring the nouns to do all the work. Plus, without an additional sentence, no one will understand what you mean by "support the internet." Pretend instead that you're telling a story, not trying to imitate an academic style that even well executed is as dull as cold oatmeal. Otherwise, this type of proofreading question fall outside the framework of this site.

Comment: You might want to consider the meaning of your sentence once more. You say that there is **an acute understanding** that to (...) the internet **would need to be supported**. You use a lot of words, but it's still not clear what you mean by **supported**. You could rewrite it as: _as internet penetration increased, it became apparent that a free internet requires **<whatever you mean by supported>**_. That way, you emphasise the **supported** part. You could put something else at the end to stress it, but try not to waste as many words on the less relevant parts.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. The phrases you mention in your problem description don’t appear in your example. Are you looking for something more conceptual?

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, as global internet penetration increased there was an acute understanding that for access to the internet to remain free the internet would need to be supported.

How about something like this, getting rid of "there was" and "would need to be":

Additionally, as global internet penetration increased, so did the acute understanding that a free internet needs support.